# List Iteration and editing list's items, Please improve my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = ['also', 'akin', 'akee', 'ague', 'aero', 
     'anes', 'bute', 'byre', 'came', 'case', 
     'doze', 'down', 'drek', 'drew', 'dyes', 
     'fret', 'freo']
i = 'e'
b = []

for item in a:
    for chr in item:
        if chr != i:
            b.append(item.replace(chr,"-"))          

print(b)
```

Print results:

```
['-lso', 'a-so', 'al-o', 'als-', '-kin', 'a-in', 'ak-n', 'aki-', '-kee', 'a-ee', '-gue', 'a-ue', 'ag-e', '-ero', 'ae-o', 'aer-', '-nes', 'a-es', 'ane-', '-ute', 'b-te', 'bu-e', '-yre', 'b-re', 'by-e', '-ame', 'c-me', 'ca-e', '-ase', 'c-se', 'ca-e', '-oze', 'd-ze', 'do-e', '-own', 'd-wn', 'do-n', 'dow-', '-rek', 'd-ek', 'dre-', '-rew', 'd-ew', 'dre-', '-yes', 'd-es', 'dye-', '-ret', 'f-et', 'fre-', '-reo', 'f-eo', 'fre-']
```

In the above example, `a` is a list of words. For each item in the list, I want to iterate through each character.  If a character is not a letter `'e'`, then replace the character with a dash `'-'`.

So, the word `"also"` which does not have an `'e'` should become `"----"`, not four different items each with a dash at different position.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the innermost part of your loop, you are scanning each *letter*. But in the code you have, you are appending an item to `b` there. So for each *letter* of your input, you have a full string of output - not what you want, it seems.

Try this:

```
for item in a:
    bitem = ''
    for chr in item:
        if chr != i:
            bitem += '-'
        else:
            bitem += chr
    b.append(bitem)
```

That being said, there are other ways to accomplish this that might be simpler.
See the other fine answers for other techniques - I'm just giving a corrected version of your original code.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code. I'm an absolute beginner to Python. I'm current taking my first CS101 programming class with no previous programming experiences. I'm just learning the very basics at the moment. Although it's enlightening to view the advanced techniques in other answers

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension and [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
lst = ['also', 'akin', 'akee', 'ague', 'aero',
     'anes', 'bute', 'byre', 'came', 'case', 
     'doze', 'down', 'drek', 'drew', 'dyes', 
     'fret', 'freo']

i = 'e'

new_lst = []

for item in lst:
    new_lst.append(''.join('-' if c != i else c for c in item))

print new_lst
```

Output:

```
['----', '----', '--ee', '---e', '-e--', '--e-', '---e', '---e', '---e', '---e', '---e', '----', '--e-', '--e-', '--e-', '--e-', '--e-']
```

Comment: I'm in my first (CS101)programming class. I've never been show the list comprehension method.  Your method is so much simpler. It's just like writing a command sentence in plain English.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest using regular expression substitution here.

Create a regular expression that matches all non-e characters and map a function that replaces each non-e character with a '-' to each element in `a`.

```
import re
not_e = re.compile(r'[^e]')
b = map(lambda word: not_e.sub('-', word), a)
```

One liner for the above code:

```
b = map(lambda word: re.sub(r'[^e]', '-', word), a)
```

If you want to stick with the more verbose syntax, you can also loop through and append as in your question.

```
for word in a:
    b.append(non_e.sub('-', word))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['also', 'akin', 'akee', 'ague', 'aero', 
     'anes', 'bute', 'byre', 'came', 'case', 
     'doze', 'down', 'drek', 'drew', 'dyes', 
     'fret', 'freo']
i = 'e'

for b in range(0, len(a)):
    k = list(a[b])
    for i in range(0, len(k)):
        if k[i] != 'e':
            k[i] = '-'
    k = ''.join(k)
    a[b] = k
```

Use double `for` loops, one for getting each word, and one for looping through each of its characters. From there, you can check if each is 'e'.

Output:

```
['----', '----', '--ee', '---e', '-e--', '--e-', '---e', '---e', '---e', '---e', '---e', '----', '--e-', '--e-', '--e-', '--e-', '--e-']
```

Answer (score 0):

No fancy looping needed:

```
[''.join(c if c == 'e' else '-' for c in s) for s in a]
```